# Why doesn't this Sage program work properly (Project Euler 23)?

Tags: python, sage

This is my solution to problem 23 of Project Euler, which is:

"A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28 is a perfect number.

A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.

As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.

Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers."

I have written this code, but for some reason it gives me `4190404` which is, according to the Project Euler website is incorrect.

```
import numpy

def lowfactor(n):
    factors = [i for i in xrange(2, ceil(sqrt(n))) if n % i == 0]

    return list(numpy.unique(factors))

def factor(n):
    low = lowfactor(n)
    factors = [n / i for i in low]
    factors.reverse()
    factors = factors + low

    return factors

def isAbundant(n):
    factors = factor(n)
    factorSum = sum(factors)

    return factorSum > n

abundants = [i for i in xrange(28124) if isAbundant(i)]

sums = map(lambda n: False, range(28124))

for a in xrange(0, len(abundants)):
    for b in xrange(a, len(abundants)):
        if (abundants[a] + abundants[b]) < 28124:
            sums[abundants[a] + abundants[b]] = True

notsums = []
for i in xrange(28124):
    if not sums[i]:
        notsums.append(i)

sumofnotsums = sum(notsums)

print(sumofnotsums)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll see the problem if you calculate factor(28) and compare your result to answer given by Euler.

Comment: Yes, I switched to using the `divisors()` function provided by Sage, and the program was fixed.